# Criar tabela csv em python

Tags: python, csv

Estou tentando construir uma tabela a partir de informações coletadas em um site.

O problema é que apesar do print sair como o esperado, na hora de salvar no arquivo csv está indo apenas o último registro.

Abaixo o trecho de código que está me dando dor de cabeça.

```
titulo = 0
atributo = 1
alinhado = ""

with open(arquivoOutput, 'w') as csvfile:
    escrevelinha = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    escrevelinha.writerow(["Matricula","Servidor","Cargo","Referência","Remuneração","Abono","Eventuais", "Descontos", "Salario Liquido"])


    while (titulo < 18):
        apenastag1 = str(apenastag.find_all("td")[titulo].get_text())
        apenastag2 = str(apenastag.find_all("td")[atributo].get_text())
        #print(apenastag2)
        alinhado = alinhado + apenastag2 + ";"

        titulo = titulo + 2
        atributo = atributo + 2

    alinhado = alinhado + "\n"
    print(alinhado)
    escrevelinha.writerow([alinhado])
```

A saída do print é a seguinte:

[image: Saída print]

O print está saindo exatamente como o esperado.

Já o arquivo CSV tem apenas o último registro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como soluciono isso?

Comment: Já tentou usar o `write()` ao invés do `writerow()`?

Answer (score 2):

Mova essa linha:

`escrevelinha.writerow([alinhado])`

Que está fora do `while`, para dentro do mesmo, pois assim a cada interação e busca do elemento , já estará sendo feita a gravação no csv.

Comment: Há a possibilidade de gravar essa string com um único [writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)?

Comment: Sim, é. o writerows recebe um iterável como argumento para poder ser escrito, com isso vc cria uma lista ( como exemplo de iterável ) onde cada item dela será uma linha. Com isso dentro do whilte vc vai criando os elementos e inserindo dentro dessa lista, e fora do for usa o writerows para ser feita a escrita.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Ou faça assim usando a ILDE-Python no banco Nosql especializado em CSV chamado CSV Comp DB:

```
import cql_to_python
db ="path\\dbfolder\\"
table = "Mytable"
cql = str("")
cql = create_table(db,table) #cria tablea csv
cql = cql + create_fields(db,table,"(ID ; FIELD1 ; FIELD2)") #cria campos
cql = cql + add_data(db,table,"(0001 ; DATA1 ; DATA2)") #add dados
CSV_COMP_DB_execute(cql) #executa o banco de dados
```

Answer (score 0):

Será que se mudar o parâmetro "w" por "a" não ficaria bem melhor? Pois o w (write) sobrescreve o que já havia sido armazenado enquanto que o a (append), acrescenta mais um item a "lista".